# Json chuck facts parsing

Tags: c++, c, json, chuck

Well, i have this [link](http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random) and i want to parse through it and get only the joke. Its in json format. I would like to use c or c++, not python because i already did it with python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.json.org/) is a pretty impressive list of JSON parsers. Take your pick, C and C++ are certainly both supported.

Comment: Tried with jsoncpp but just cant get it to work, i used this command in python return json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())['value']['joke'].encode('ascii','ignore') for urlopen i will use libcurl

Comment: @BKovac: Maybe post the source code of your attempt using jsoncpp (as an edit to your question), along with a description of the problems you encountered (or error messages while compiling)?

Comment: Ok, well, i stopped using jsoncpp and started json-c

Comment: Can someone please tell how to json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(URL).read())['value']['joke'].encode('ascii','ignore'‌​) in c with json-c?

Comment: Only a example please, i'll do everything else